# How to use a custom binding to animate elements being added using "foreach" in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-animate

I have an array of images that I want to add to a page using the knockout.js "foreach" function like so:

```
<div class="animation" data-bind="foreach: { data: frames }">
    <img data-bind="fadeInVisible: true" src="./media/test.jpg" />
</div>
```

My custom binding is:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeInVisible = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); // Get the current value of the current property we're bound to
        $(element).hide().delay("1000").fadeIn(); // jQuery will hide/show the element depending on whether "value" or true or false
    }
};
```

My problem is that they all come in at the same time, where I want them to come in staggered. Is there a nice way to stagger them I can do using knockout?

I was thinking I could maybe use a jQuery queue to add an animation to the queue when I call my custom binding and then at the end I could run the animation queue but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the delay by the index of the item in foreach loop. Item zero would be 0*1000ms, item 1 would have a delay of 1*1000ms etc.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="animation" data-bind="foreach: { data: frames }">
    <img data-bind="fadeInVisible: true" src="./media/test.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeInVisible = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var index = $index();
        $(element).hide().delay(index * 1000).fadeIn();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's a nice simple and concise answer.